# Cakephp : language translation to german all chars not showing properly

Tags: php

I have a multi language site (German & English) in cakephp . But here is a problem dealing with , I am not able to properly display German special characters.

See below German version

> Verg�tung

Even I defined the charset.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Anybody can tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your pages have the correct HTTP header! Check with [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) in the network tab if they are transmitted as UTF-8!